# Acer Aspire V3-772g IOMMU?

Tags: acer-aspire, pci

I am using an Acer-Aspire-V3-772G-747a161-12TMakk and want to install Linux as host and a Windows Edition as guest on a VM. To be able to play games there I want to use PCI passthrough and therefore I need IOMMU support from Mainboard and CPU (as far as I know)
Unfortunately I can't find any information about that. 
Can you tell me if this will work?

Tank you.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Searching for your laptop model leads me to believe you have  the [i7-4702](https://ark.intel.com/products/75119).

VT-d is Intel's [IOMMU](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel-VT-d) implementation and the [specification page](https://ark.intel.com/products/75119) for your processor clearly states that it is **not** supported.

[image]

You will not be able to use PCI passthrough.